# Create audiobook with Bing speech API

Tags: c#, .net, azure, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I would like to know if there is a way to create audiobooks using bing speech api. That is to say, I would like to create an audiobook having a txt as an input. Nowadays the API restricts speech generation to 1024 characters. AWS has an "automatic" solution for it, using [amazon polly and aws batch](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/create-audiobooks-with-amazon-polly-and-aws-batch/): [image]

I did not figure it out how to do it in Azure. Is there a generic way to do this in Azure?

Comment: Not sure what your specific question is. There is no built-in "create audiobook" feature of the Cognitive Services APIs - you'd need to create whatever content you want, based on your app, your code, etc.

Comment: Another way to ask it: how can we override the 1024 character limit restriction in the speech api? Do I have to gather different audio pieces and put them together manually? As I show it in my question, amazon has a built in solution for this particular problem.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the [Speech API client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedclientlibraries) would help with what you need.

From the docs:

> Support more advanced capabilities in speech recognition, such as intermediate results in real time, long audio stream (up to 10 minutes), and continuous recognition.

Comment: No, but I thought the above could be part of a solution that could be tried.